# How to batch create empty .txt files from folderA to forlderB with original date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have folderA with some .mxf files C0001.mxf, C0002.mxf, C0003.mxf, C0004.mxf, C0005.mxf, C0006.mxf ecc..

I would like generate empty files in folderB to achieve:

C0001.txt [empty], C0002.txt, C0003.txt etc.. and all files have to be the same date of original .mxf files

If folderB have jet (e.g.) C0001.txt, then the new C0001.txt overwrite the previous

Possibly the batch file must ask me to specify, to type "folderA" and start when I press the return on the keyboard.

Is it possible? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
@echo off
set destination=c:\folderb
set /p source=Enter source path:
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" *.mxf /create
ren "%destination%\*.mxf" *.txt
```